# Toggle color of an <a href> in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a 2D square that toggles between "classes" to change color. When it's clicked, it turns blue. When it's clicked again, it turns back to gray. Code below!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .square {
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 4px;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #D2D7D3;
    }

    .blue {
      background: #446CB3;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="square" id="b1"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
<!-- changes square color -->
    $("#b1").click(function() {
      $('#b1').toggleClass('blue');
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now I'm trying to replicate this toggle feature with a 3D square, but have not been successful. So when it's clicked, it should turn blue and *stay blue* until it's clicked again. Then when clicked again, it should turn back to gray. (Just like in the 2D version.) Below is my current non-working code!

Thanks in advance for any advice!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .square {
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 4px;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .square a {
      color: #B6BBB7;
      font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 36px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #B6BBB7;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      padding: 20px 40px;

      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      filter: dropshadow(color=#000, offx=0px, offy=1px);

      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #D2D7D3, 0 10px 0 #505551;
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #D2D7D3, 0 10px 0 #505551;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #D2D7D3, 0 10px 0 #505551;

      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .square a:active {
      top: 10px;
      color: #446CB3;
      background-color: #446CB3;

      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #B6D5FF, inset 0 -3px 0 #003D7E;
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #B6D5FF, inset 0 -3pxpx 0 #003D7E;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #B6D5FF, inset 0 -3px 0 #003D7E;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="pageLoad();">
  <div id="experiment">
    <div id="shape_container">
      <div ontouchstart="" class="square" id="b1"><a href="#">b1</a></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#b1").click(function() {
        // haven't figured out how to write correct toggle code here!
      });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of targeting the `:active` state, add it as a class:

```js
$("#b1").click(function() {
  $(this).children('a').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.square {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.square a {
  color: #B6BBB7;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #B6BBB7;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 40px;

  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  filter: dropshadow(color=#000, offx=0px, offy=1px);

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #D2D7D3, 0 10px 0 #505551;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #D2D7D3, 0 10px 0 #505551;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #D2D7D3, 0 10px 0 #505551;

  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.square a.active {
  top: 10px;
  color: #446CB3;
  background-color: #446CB3;

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #B6D5FF, inset 0 -3px 0 #003D7E;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #B6D5FF, inset 0 -3pxpx 0 #003D7E;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #B6D5FF, inset 0 -3px 0 #003D7E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="experiment">
  <div id="shape_container">
    <div ontouchstart="" class="square" id="b1"><a href="#">b1</a></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
.square a:active{...}
```

to

```
.square a.active{...}
```

Modify the click function as below

```
$("#b1").click(function() {
    // Toggle active class
    $("#b1 > a").toggleClass('active');
});
```

See the working example in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/arfizurrahman/pen/QWbbLzb)